# fdisk -l return cannot open /proc/partitions

Tags: debian, openvz, disk-space-utilization, partition

I have a Debian server with 4.5Go on the /dev/simfs partition.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      4.5G  3.2G  1.3G  72% /
tmpfs           474M   76K  474M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           947M     0  947M   0% /run/shm
```

I asked my provider to increase the disk space and I would like now to increase the size of the partition but I cannot even use 
fdisk -l as it returns

```
cannot open /proc/partitions
```

I am a beginner with servers, is it normal that I can't access this command (I am logged as root)?

**EDIT :**

```
cat /proc/mounts
/dev/simfs / simfs rw,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=484820k,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=969620k 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
```

Comment: What does `cat /proc/mounts` have to say?

Comment: A quick search suggests `simfs` is an OpenVZ specific file system. If your system is running on OpenVZ, you should add an [tag:openvz] tag to your question.

Comment: I don't know... How can I be sure? I tried some commands like vzlist but I got "command not found"...

Comment: vzlist is the command you'ld run on your OpenVZ hypervisor. This indeed looks like some OpenVZ VE.

Answer (score 1):

/proc/partitions does not exist under OpenVZ. The container isn't a "true" Linux system, so a lot of things don't appear.

Comment: This answer could be more useful if it explained the necessary steps to grow a simfs file system under OpenVZ.

Comment: if youn want to resize the fs of your openvz container you can try vzctl set CTID --diskspace  40G --save

Comment: How can I know how much space is available ?

Comment: You need access to the hypervisor, to run vzctl commands or check available space. Depending on your case, this could be reserved to your hosting provider. OpenVZ filesystem is usually just a subdir on your hypervisor: available space would be seen using something like `df -h`. Bumping quotas, you should give a look to your other VEs current quotas and disk usage.